# discord.py tenor api am i doing this wrong?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def oppai1(ctx):
 async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
  embed = discord.Embed (
        title = 'OPPAI',
        description = "Here's Ya OPPAI!",
        colour = discord.Colour.blue())
      
  response = await session.get('https://api.tenor.com/v1/search?q=oppai&key=85LY8DY0JV3Q&limit=30&media_filter=basic')
  data = json.loads(await response.text())
  gif_choice = random.randint(0,29)
  embed.set_image(url=data['weburl'][gif_choice]['gif']['url'])

  await session.close()
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I'm new so I kinda don't know anymore need halp, I'm trying it to only send 'oppai' GIF : ) also pls don't say I'm bad I'm just a dum-dum and new. ( Giphy worked fine for me but its search relevance is really bad it's supposed to be an oppai search it would send a different gif, whilst tenor is very relevant to its search)
Someone pls halp ;-;

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be more careful with your API key. It's like your password to the tenor API, so try not to write it on StackExchange.

As for the solution, I believe you just need replace `['weburl']` with `['results']` in `url=data['weburl'][gif_choice]['gif']['url']`.